# About the verb "talk"

Tags: verbs

> 1. Let's talk about how to learn English efficiently.
> 2. Let's talk how to learn English efficiently

There is any difference in meaning?

I think that the 2 is more direct to the topic than the 1.

Comment: To my ear, 2 is very colloquial: I wouldn't say it. For me "talk" takes a direct object only in a few fixed idioms like "talk business" or "talk brass tacks" or "talk turkey" (all of which have approximately the same meaning).

Comment: @Colin Fine Due to the fact that Korean has nothing to do with English in any way, it is too difficult for me to know precisely what is the genuine meaning of the verb 'talk'. I have looked up many dictionaries, I cannot catch up the feeling of the verb 'talk', though. Could you tell me what is the definite meaning? As far as I know, it would mean "say to each other". And I think, although I don't know it would be correct or not, that the meaning of a verb is criteria to verdict whether the verb can take a direct object or not.

Comment: Unfortunately, @Evariste Galois, the assumption in your last sentence is wrong. Knowing the meaning is not enough to determine what kind of objects a verb can take.There are many examples of verb with very similar meanings that require different arguments. So _say_ always (or nearly always) requires a direct object, that represents the actual words spoken: often the direct quotation, or else  an indirect quotation (_say that .... _) but sometimes a noun phrase like "the words". _Talk_ does not usually take a direct object; and _speak_ can be used with or without a direct object.